# Rails: disable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, fancybox

I have a rails application that gets called from an ajax request on a plain HTML page. Rails responds and the plain HTML page loads data from my rails app into [fancybox](http://www.fancybox.net).

The problem is that when trying to close fancybox using `$.fancybox.close();` I get an undefined error.  However, if I only feed an html link referencing `$.fancybox.close();`  without loading my rails application, fancybox closes with no issue.

This leads me to believe that jquery included in my application.js is conflicting with the jquery that's loaded on my plain HTML page. How can I tell rails not to send jquery? I already have it loaded where the rails app is being sent.  If I could disable this in production only, that would be ideal.

I have already tried removing `//=require jquery` and `//=require jquery_ujs` and even `//=require_tree .` from application.js with no luck; application.js still loads with jquery present.  Any ideas?

Comment: could you paste trace of error? it's on browser console,

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'close' of undefined VM383:1
(anonymous function)`   I honestly think I need to use `jquery.noconflict();` to avoid them from conflicting, that should work, right? @juanpastas